# zero in excel but not zero in vba

Tags: excel, vba, math

In vba i manipulated 2 ranges to populate 2 different 2-d arrays of variant type, tempArr(,1) numeric result of formula (rounded to 2dp), tempArr(,2) string data type

i have copied the arrays into new worksheet:

```
Dim tempArr(1 to 50, 1 to 2) as Variant
Range("A1:A50") = tempArr
Range("C1:C100") =tempArr1
```

I then have a subroutine to perform a comparison:

```
Dim myRg as Range
Dim myArr() as Variant
Set myRg = Range("A1",Cells(lastrow,4))
myArr = myRg
```

but when i loop (I,J,K) through the numeric column A with column C trying to match:

```
If myArr(I,1)- myArr(J,3)-myArr(k,3) = 0 Then ' perform action
```

...the logic fails in only one instance where in excel worksheet the calculation is clearly 0 but in vba the value is 2.546E-09

First question relates to why numbers in excel worksheet which are to 2dp would in vba create a value, after addition/subtraction calculation, with 9th decimal place or more. Or is 2.546E-09 result caused by something else?

Secondly I have used array of variant type to efficiently handle the 2 data types, but perhaps not the best when it comes to performing math. operations..Would creating a variable of Double data type be the solution for the above issue..? i have just started using variant array method to manipulate range data which has speeded up my routines considerably but any general advice would be appreciated. This is my first post so pls bear with me.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113

Answer (score 2):

2.546E-09 = 0.000000002546. The reason this exists even though you were doing simple arithmetic is simply the nature of a floating point error. The simplest way to resolve this in your case is to make your comparison to 0 rounded, like so:

```
If Round(myArr(I,1) - myArr(J,3) - myArr(k,3), 0) = 0 Then
```